# Twitter OAuth problems with angularfire Yeoman generator

Tags: angularjs, twitter, oauth, yeoman, angularfire

AngularFire Yeoman generator works like a charm providing OAuth authentication for Facebook and Google, but I'm not able to get it working with Twitter :(

Login view/controller created by the generator works as follows:

1. Call oauthLogin('twitter') from view.
2. oauthLogin is just a wrapper of simpleLogin.login:

   ```
   $scope.oauthLogin = function(provider) {
         $scope.err = null;
         simpleLogin.login(provider, {rememberMe: true}).then(redirect, showError);
       };
   ```
3. simpleLogin.login is a wrapper of $authWithOAuthPopup:

   ```
   login: function(provider, opts) {
             return auth.$authWithOAuthPopup(provider, opts);
           }
   ```
4. So, at the end of the day, it is just a call to $authWithOAuthPopup provided by firebase.js.

As I mentioned before, Facebook and Google works fine, but when I tried with Twitter, I got this error:

```
{"error":{"code":"ROUTE_NOT_FOUND","message":"Route not found."}}
```

This is because I end the OAuth process in a wrong callback URL: https://auth.firebase.com/v2/MYAPP/auth/twitter instead of https://auth.firebase.com/v2/MYAPP/auth/twitter/callback, and I don't know how to fix this.

Any hint about this callback URL issue with Twitter OAuth in AngularFire?

Thanks in advance ;)